# Flutter issue on passing variable to GraphQl query

Tags: laravel, flutter, graphql

This is a very simple `GraphQl` query which that implemented in `Laravel` and work fine in `graphql-playground` or `RestClient` applications

```
type Query {
    user(id: ID @eq): User @find(model:"App\\Models\\User")
}


type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    email: String
}
```

for example when i try to get query like with:

```
query{
   user(id:9)
     id
     name
     email
}
```

that can a `user` that is is `9`.

now inside `Flutter` i want to use this `query` with passing any `id` for `user` method and when i try to do this i get this error:

```
The following SourceSpanException was thrown building UserList(dirty):
Error on line 1, column 23: Expected an argument name
  ╷
1 │           query{ user($id : Int!){
  │                       ^
  ╵
```

my code:

```dart
class UserList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Query(
      options: QueryOptions(
        document: gql(r'''
          query{ user($id : Int!){
            name
            id
          }
          }
        '''),
        variables:{
          'id': 9,
        },
      ),
      builder: (
        QueryResult result, {
        Future<QueryResult> Function(FetchMoreOptions)? fetchMore,
        Future<QueryResult?> Function()? refetch
      }) {
        if (result.data != null){
          print(result.data);
        }
        /// return widget
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATED**

now changing query inside `Flutter` as posted new solution under my question to:

```dart
document: gql(r'''
  query GetUser($id: Int!) { 
    user(id : $id) {
        name
        id
    }
  }
'''),
variables:{
  'id': 9,
},
```

i don't get error, but it doesn't return any result

Comment: so to clarify, you're getting no results when doing this via this query, but you still get results when you make this call through GraphQL Playground?

Comment: same..may I know how you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your query in the client does not seem to be correct for handling variables. Check https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables. Here is how it probably should look like for your client:

```
query GetUser($id: Int!) { 
    user(id : $id) {
        name
        id
    }
}
```

Comment: i changed `flutter` code to `options: QueryOptions( document: gql(r''' query GetUser($id: Int!) {  user(id : $id) { name  id } }  '''), variables: { 'id': 9,  }, ),` but i don't get any result now

Comment: I recommend you add that additional information in the question as an edit, rather than here, since it is unreadable here in the comments.

Comment: @DanCrews i updated the question, please review that again